# Java Code to Implement a hash table using only arrays

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I'll preface this comment by saying that I understand how a hash table works however I'm not sure how I would go about implementing one from scratch using only primitives.

Would anyone be able to provide a Java code implementation of a hash table using only arrays?

How would I even start writing a hash table in Java?

How would I code a linked-list hash table again using only primitives?

Cheers!

Comment: Luke, use the source.

Comment: Have a look at the [OpenJDK source code of `java.util.HashMap`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html). Or the source code bundled with your JDK :-)

Comment: @PéterTörök dang, beat me to it - docjar's search is super slow right now

Comment: If you understand how hash tables work, then presumably you can be a little more specific with your question.  What, specifically, is the bit that you can't figure out?

Comment: Using only primitive key / values? Or are you saying an Array is a primitive?

Comment: If you're coding a linked-list hash table you won't be using "only primitives" -- you'll have to create a helper `Node<T>` class for your linked list, at the very least. (The generic is optional).

Comment: If you don't understand how you would implement a hash table from scratch, then either you don't have the programming skills, or you don't really understand the data structure.  Either way, I don't know how this question will help you.  You are better of just trying to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The code given by the OpenJDK can be pretty hard to understand, so I'll write a short idea how to do it...

One way I did it recently was to use the array itself as a symbol table. The indices of the array will then be the keys (hash-keys) and the elements the value (whatever you want to store). Since arrays have a fixed size and hash-keys can be any integer we are faced with a challenge: to crop the hash-values so they are in the same range as the size of the array. If, say the array has a length of 5, the keys needs to be between 0 and 4. Otherwise we would place values into slots outside of the array => lots and lots of exceptions.

This challenge becomes especially fun when you'd like to avoid collisions...

A lot of help can be found on [this page on princeton](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/).

Good luck!